# Oracle forms insert a new record from an existing one

Tags: oracle, sql-insert, oracleforms

Is there a way to disable updating data in a form i.e. when we navigate through a block and we modify a field ; a new line is inserted whithout updating the original tuple ?
Thank you in avance.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way - from my point of view - is to modify data block's **Update allowed** property to "No". It will force users to insert new rows.

Moreover, Forms' toolbar allows them to **duplicate record** so that they wouldn't have to type everything from scratch - duplicate previous row and update whatever needed.

If you thought of some other option, I'm afraid you'll have to write some code to enforce it (your own trigger(s)).